# plot.gam and draw.gam produce different smooths for same GAMM object when using factor smooths

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I've been experimenting with plotting different GAMMs using the plot.gam function from the mgcv package and draw.gam function from the gratia package. When plotting a GAMM with a beta distribution (using factor smooths as 'random effects'), I noticed the smooths were different. In large, they have the same shape, but the smooths do differ, and I was wondering if I have coded something wrong, or if there are differences between the functions I have overlooked when dealing with factor smooths? Without factor smooths, these differences were not present.

I have the newest version of the package gratia installed.

My concrete question is: Is there a reason for these differences in the smooths?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
devtools::install_github('gavinsimpson/gratia')
library(gratia)

data <- gamSim(4, 400) %>%
  mutate(rand = rep(letters[1:4], each = 100), rand = as.factor(rand))

model_3 <- bam(
  y ~
    s(x2, by = fac) +
    s(x2, rand, by = fac, bs = "fs", m = 1),
  data = data
)

draw(model_3, fun = plogis, constant = (coef(model_3)[1]), 
     select = c(1,2,3)) & theme_bw()

plot(model_3, 
     shade = TRUE, 
     shade.col = "lightblue", 
     shift = coef(model_3)[1], 
     trans = plogis, 
     seWithMean = T, 
     pages = 1)
```

Would be grateful for input! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to have messed something up there. I was editing this code very recently. I'll double check.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug introduced in 0.7.0-1 when I edited the code to fix a separate problem and made a silly mistake. I didn't catch it as this wasn't being tested before and I didn't notice the error when I looked at the test output when I edited the code and wrote tests.

The issue was that while the constant was being added in the `add_constant()` call, the code didn't return the modified object. Instead the original object was being return by `add_constant()`.

I have fixed this locally and will push the fix to GitHub shortly. Look for version 0.7.0-5